# Proving a graph is planar given vertices and boundary edges

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given that a graph has 12  vertices  and  every  region  has
four boundary edges, I need to find its number of edges, regions, and then prove if it is planar.

Comment: I’m a bit confused about your question. If it is unknown if G is planar, what do you mean by regions?

Comment: By regions I mean faces (regions bounded by edges).

Comment: What is a face if the graph is not planar?

Comment: Yes, but you can only have regions if the graph is embedded without crossings. Is it embedded in some surface of unknown genus?

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction so I'm assuming the graph is planar.

Comment: If you are trying to show that the graph is planar, as your question suggests, then you cannot assume it is planar. If you want to use a proof by contradiction, you would assume the graph is not planar.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v=12$ be the number of vertices, let $e$ be the number of edges and let $f$ be the number of regions.

The graph is planar so by Euler we have $v-e+f=2$. Each region has $4$ edges (this will double count the edges) so $4f=2e$ (or $2f=e$) so ...

> $v=12,e=20,f=10$

[image]